# Unable to request Android permission using Plugin.Permissions in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, shared-libraries, android-permissions

I am developing an application using Xamarin.Forms. In my application, I need to access the camera. But before I access, I need to ask permission from the user for Android Device. So, for asking permission from the user, I am using this plugin, https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.Permissions. This is what I have done so far.

I installed the package using nuget. When I installed the package, MainApplication.cs file is added to the Android project. Then in the MainActivity.cs file, I override the OnRequestPermissionsResult method. 
So, this is my MainActivity class in the Android project.

```
[Activity(Label = "MementoApp.Android", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MyTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
   public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
   {
      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
      {

         TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
         ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

         base.OnCreate(bundle);

         global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);

         LoadApplication(new App());
      }

      protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
      {
         base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      }


        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

In the CameraPage in the Shared project, I try to pop up the alert that requests the camera permission from the user as follow.

```
private async void RequestAndroidCameraPermission()
        {
            var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Camera);
            var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Camera);
            //Best practice to always check that the key exists
            if (results.ContainsKey(Permission.Camera))
                status = results[Permission.Camera];
       }
```

I am calling that method after the `InitializeComponent()` method. But when I run my application, no pop up comes up to ask camera permission. What is missing my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: did you read all the instructions in the docs?  https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin

Comment: Yes. I followed it step by step. As you can see in the question, I set up the MainApplication class and the overrided the OnRequestPermissionsResult method in the MainActivity.cs.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I am experiencing the same problem...

Comment: No., I stopeed using Xamarin. It is literally shit